# Considering network traffic in iPhone apps for users's benefit

Tags: ios, networking, ios5, apple-push-notifications, cellular-network

In the iPhone apps, network traffic via cellular network usually will cost users money by sending network request etc, so we need try to avoid such architecture or technical solutions for the apps to avoid cost much money for users.

Does that make sense ? And also try to look for any policy from Apple about this, any clues ?

As I know Apple push notification should be better than such polling approach which need send request to server periodically.

What are the alternative solutions in such cases ?

Answer (score 1):

You could test to see if the user if on Wifi or the cellular network (use Reachability for this). If they are on the cellular network warn them that you are going to be using a lot of data.

It's also important to only load data when necessary. Don't download all your data when the app loads. Do it when the view appears (and do it in a background thread to prevent the UI locking).

You should optimise any data you will be downloading. e.g. if you are going to download a load of images or audio files download a compressed (zip) file containing them and then unzip it on the device.

Comment: Yes. Agree with those optimization strategy: check network type,compressing data, and prevent UI freezing etc. But strongly believe that APNs should be better solution than the polling approach, even with a lot optimized. How do you think ?

Comment: @Forrest I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Do you know APNs ( Apple Push Notification Service ) ? My point is that this tech should be the best solution which can cover such issues in terms of benefit of users.

Comment: @Forrest I am familiar with Push Notifications. Which are you trying to use it to do?